# Dynamic Datahousekeeping by Batch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 30 tables, each containing 200 million plus rows to housekeep / purge. The average rows to be deleted will be around 900K - 5Mil. I used the stored procedure below and its taking 30min to delete 1 table. Is there away to reduce the time when executing it.

This T-SQL will read a config table like this:

| fldTableName | fldFieldName | fldPeriodMonth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Table1 | fldImportFileName | 24 |
| Table2 | fldSubmissionDate | 32 |

`fldTableName` is for specifying the table name and `fldFieldName` is for specifying the column that contains the date. Some date columns are in string format. `fldPeriodMonth` is to specify the duration of data to keep, and the rest will be deleted.

I tried different size of batch from 5K - 5M and, but the difference is only in 1 to 5s.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTI
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DataHousekeepingByBatch_1]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @FieldName NVARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @PeriodInMonths INT;
    DECLARE @DeleteQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @RowCount INT = 0;
    DECLARE @TotalRowsAffected INT = 0;
    DECLARE @ActionTime DATETIME;
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE @Description NVARCHAR(1000);

    DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000000;  -- set batch size here


    DECLARE housekeeping_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT fldTableName, fldFieldName, fldPeriodMonth FROM dbo.tblDataHousekeepingConfig;

    OPEN housekeeping_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM housekeeping_cursor INTO @TableName, @FieldName, @PeriodInMonths;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @ActionTime = GETDATE();
        SET @ErrorMessage = NULL;
        SET @Description = 'Deletion successful';
        SET @TotalRowsAffected = 0;

        WHILE @RowCount = 0 OR @RowCount = @BatchSize
        BEGIN
            IF @FieldName = 'fldImportFileName'
            BEGIN
                SET @DeleteQuery = N'DELETE TOP (' + CAST(@BatchSize AS NVARCHAR) + ') FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + 
                                  N' WHERE CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(' + QUOTENAME(@FieldName) + ', 8), 112) <= DATEADD(MONTH, -' + CAST(@PeriodInMonths AS NVARCHAR) + ', GETDATE())';

                Print @DeleteQuery  
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @DeleteQuery = N'DELETE TOP (' + CAST(@BatchSize AS NVARCHAR) + ') FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + 
                                  N' WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, ' + QUOTENAME(@FieldName) + ', 120) <= DATEADD(MONTH, -' + CAST(@PeriodInMonths AS NVARCHAR) + ', GETDATE())';

                Print @DeleteQuery  
            END

            BEGIN TRY
                EXEC sp_executesql @DeleteQuery;
                SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SET @TotalRowsAffected = @TotalRowsAffected + @RowCount;
                IF @RowCount = 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @Description = 'No more rows affected';
                    BREAK; -- Exit the inner loop if no more rows to delete
                END
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
                SET @Description = 'Error: ' + @ErrorMessage;
                BREAK; -- Exit the inner loop on error
            END CATCH

        END

        --log
        INSERT INTO dbo.tblDataHousekeepingLog (fldTableName, fldFieldName, fldPeriodInMonths, fldActionTime, fldRowsAffected, fldDescription)
        VALUES (@TableName, @FieldName, @PeriodInMonths, @ActionTime, @TotalRowsAffected, @Description);

        FETCH NEXT FROM housekeeping_cursor INTO @TableName, @FieldName, @PeriodInMonths;
    END

    CLOSE housekeeping_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE housekeeping_cursor;
END
```

Comment: FYI SSMS is a UI and therefore not relevant to your question.

Comment: For performance questions the execution plan is required, using "Paste The Plan".

Comment: FYI databases have columns not fields.

Comment: `CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(' + QUOTENAME(@FieldName) + ', 8), 112)` This is going to kill the performance. What is the data type for `@FieldName`? If it is in `date` or `datetime`, you don't need to `convert()` it at all

Comment: Thanks Dale for the comment, im trying to get the execution plan

Comment: @Squirrel got 2 type of column, 

1.  CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(' + QUOTENAME(@FieldName) + ', 8), 112) reads nvarchar. The data look like this :  'QTM_MM_OS_20240116'



2. TRY_CONVERT(DATE, ' + QUOTENAME(@FieldName) + ', 120), also read nvarchar, The data look like this  : '2023-10-30'

Comment: Might be faster to just recreate the tables with only the data you need. Your existing query has some problematic sargability issues.